# Personal property insurance, without home insurance

Tags: united-kingdom, insurance

I'm trying to insure an engagement ring, and have been advised to look into personal property insurance. However, these schemes all seem to be a bolt-on option to home insurance or home contents cover, which are irrelevant to me since I'm not a homeowner. I'm in England, if that makes any difference.

Are there schemes available for insuring valuable property, without needing home cover too? What do they usually cover?

Comment: Theft, mainly. Damage would be nice too.

Comment: You mention below that you don't rent. Are you covered by anyone else's contents cover (e.g. if you live with your parents, or are in student accommodation)? If so, could you add the ring to their policy?

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff I can't add it to the existing cover. It's a long story that I don't particularly want to share :/

Comment: In pretty much any industrialized nation, if you have something you can't afford to lose, or a potential liability you wouldn't be able to pay, there's an insurance company willing to take your bet that the loss or liability will be realized. It can be a rider onto a policy for something else (usually saves you money) or a standalone policy.

Answer (score 1):

In the US I have seen them "bolted" onto home owners insurance. But I have also seen them added to a renters insurance policy. This is insurance that covers the contents of the apartment/condo.

In the case of an apartment/condo the building structure is insured by the owner or owners. The stuff inside the walls are covered by the renters insurance. This may reimburse the occupant if they are unable to live in the unit if there was damage to the building/unit. The coverage can also include some liability amount.

The renters insurance policy is paid for by the occupant and covers a specific amount of stuff. It will not cover very expensive items unless they are specifically listed on the policy. That is where the engagement ring, professional quality photo equipment etc. are listed and insured.

Comment: I don't rent either. I can't take out any form of insurance on the property I live in.

Comment: In the US it can cover people who live in other people homes and college dorms.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a [personal belongings policy](http://www.graham-edwards.co.uk/Insurance-for-valuable-items-and-belongings.html) in the UK.

In the US the policy is known as [Inland Marine Insurance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inland_marine_insurance).  The name goes back to a time when items were often transported on rivers and barges.  But this policy type now covers a wide range of personal properties not covered by other policies or often excluded from other policies.

> - Accounts Receivable
> - Bailee Customer's Goods
> - Builders' Risk
> - Camera and Photographic Equipment
> - Communication Towers and Equipment
> - Computer Coverage
> - Contractors Equipment
> - Commercial Floaters
> - Dealers
> - Exhibitions
> - Fine Arts
> - Furriers
> - Golf Equipment
> - Guns
> - Installation
> - Jewelers
> - Leased Property
> - Mobile Medical Equipment
> - Motor Truck Cargo
> - Museums
> - Musical Instruments
> - Processing Risks
> - Rigger's Liability
> - Scheduled Property
> - Transportation
> - Trip Transit
> - Valuable Papers
> - Warehouse Legal

Comment: I have no affilation with the Link provided for the belongings insurance.  If someone finds a better link to an independent site with a decent explanation feel free to substitute.